# WC_Subscription::update_dates( $dates, $timezone ) is no longer valid?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, woothemes

Seems as though the function 
**WC_Subscription::update_dates( $dates, $timezone )** is no longer valid in the 3.0+ update, because the of the CRUD platform?

How do I go about finding the right function to use, as this is what's on the website. I basically have a loop that gets all active subscriptions and I want to update the **next_payment_date**. Now, if you do this just through the database, it won't update, so you have to run it through this function so it updates all the schedulers etc.

If I run, something similar to this, I get a 500 error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
WC_Subscription::update_dates( array(
      'next_payment' => '2017-05-30 04:30:00'
) );
?>
```

Comment: I believe I figured it out, instead of calling it directly, I instantiated it first. My bad. IE: # SET subscription
  $sub = new WC_Subscription($subscription->ID);
  # UPDATE dates
  $sub->update_dates(array('next_payment' => $new_payment_date));

Comment: If you managed to solve your own question, post it as an answer. Others may also have the same question and come looking.

Comment: Yeah I will, just wasn't able to yet, as it was too quick. HaHa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out, instead of calling it directly, I instantiated it first.

My bad. IE: 
    I was trying to call it directly instead of instantiating it first.

```
WC_Subscription::update_dates( $dates, $timezone );

# SET subscription 
$sub = new WC_Subscription($subscription->ID); 
# UPDATE dates 
$sub->update_dates(array('next_payment' => $new_payment_date));
```